# Installing Boundless SDK

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk

Installing the Boundless SDK on ubuntu folowing [this documentation](http://suite.opengeo.org/ee/docs/4.5/webapps/install.html) and getting the below error after running the command `sudo apt-get install opengeo-webapp-sdk`

```
E: Unable to locate package opengeo-webapp-sdk
```

I have not installed any other boundless package. Has the package been removed or is it temporarily unavailable?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify whether you have already installed the OpenGeo Suite. If not, you'll either need to install OpenGeo Suite or use the standalone Boundless SDK instructions.

Comment: Is that not the standalone sdk? That error seems to be something other than a dependency issue

Comment: No, it's not related to dependencies. It's related to software sources. If you don't have OpenGeo Suite installed, you won't have the correct software repositories set up, so `apt-get install opengeo-webapp-sdk` will fail because that package is not is the standard Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to follow the "Installation with OpenGeo Suite" instructions. However, you don't have OpenGeo Suite installed. You can install OpenGeo Suite using [these instructions](http://suite.boundlessgeo.com/docs/latest/intro/installation/ubuntu/install.html).

Alternatively, use the standalone instructions from the same [documentation](http://suite.boundlessgeo.com/docs/latest/webapps/install.html#standalone-installation):

> **Standalone installation**
>
> Boundless SDK can also be installed on a machine that does not have
>   OpenGeo Suite.
>
> 1. A Java Development Kit (JDK) will need to be installed and configured. The standard Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is not sufficient. After installation, to verify this is available, execute the command `javac -version` from the command prompt.
> 2. This package depends on Apache Ant . After installation, to verify this is available, execute the command ant -version from a command prompt.
> 3. Download Boundless SDK from [boundlessgeo.com](http://boundlessgeo.com/products/opengeo-suite/other-components/), making sure to match the version of the SDK with the version of OpenGeo Suite.
> 4. Extract the archive to a suitable location on the file system.
> 5. Add the SDK bin directory to the PATH.
> 6. To verify the SDK is installed properly, execute the command `suite-sdk` from a command prompt.

Note: I've updated the link to the [Boundless SDK downloads](http://boundlessgeo.com/products/opengeo-suite/other-components/) in the quoted instructions as the link in the [documentation](http://suite.boundlessgeo.com/docs/latest/webapps/install.html#standalone-installation) is broken.

Comment: The link the the documentation to the SDK is a 404.  Are there any other download sources?